# Merging Two XML Documents in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my two xml documents,

```
 XmlDocument Read_XML_Id=new XmlDocument();
 string xml_id = ServiceClient.QueryObjectsAsXml(sessionId, "["+id+"]","", "", "id", "");
 Read_XML_Id.LoadXml(xml_id);

 XmlDocument Read_XML_recurs = new XmlDocument();
 string Read_xml_count= ServiceClient.QueryObjectsAsXml(sessionId, "[" + id + "].childobjects", "", "", "id", "");
 Read_XML_recurs.LoadXml(Read_xml_count);
```

I am trying to do in below way on the basis of the study I did from other same kinds of question

```
 foreach(var childNode in Read_XML_Id.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
      {
         Read_XML_recurs.DocumentElement.AppendChild(childNode);
      }
```

I am getting an error as follows,

The best overload method match for 'system.xml.xmlnodes.appendchild(system.xml.xmlnode)' has some invalid arguments
I want to append the xml content of one string into another so that I can parse the content of both string together,

my first xml_id string content below data,

```
"<ResultSetHierarchy totalResultsReturned=\"1\" totalResults=\"1\" firstIndex=\"0\" 
  maxCount=\"-1\">\r\n  
    <object id=\"SC.1938773693.1856501971\" />\r\n
 </ResultSetHierarchy>"
```

and second Read_xml_count string contains,

```
"<ResultSetHierarchy totalResultsReturned=\"4\" totalResults=\"4\" firstIndex=\"0\" 
   maxCount=\"-1\">
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.2003244210\" />
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.1129051616\" />
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.182363421\" />
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.1706904642\" />
 </ResultSetHierarchy>"
```

I finally want the content of second Read_xml_count string data to be as below,

```
 "<ResultSetHierarchy totalResultsReturned=\"4\" totalResults=\"4\" firstIndex=\"0\" 
   maxCount=\"-1\">
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.1856501971\" />--------Data from first XML string
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.2003244210\" />
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.1129051616\" />
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.182363421\" />
     <object id=\"SC.1938773693.1706904642\" />
 </ResultSetHierarchy>"
```

any help will be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following LINQ solution instead

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Parse(xml_id);
XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml_read);
xdoc2.Root.AddFirst(xdoc1.Root.Elements("object"));

Console.WriteLine(xdoc2.ToString());

foreach (var item in xdoc2.Root.Descendants("object"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} from {2}", item.Attribute("id").Name, item.Attribute("id").Value, item.ToString());
}
```

The result is an `XDocument` that will contain the merged documents.

Comment: @kami...how I am suppose to get the element from xdoc2 which is tagged as object..becaues when I am using xmldocument..then I am reading the element tagged as object as var get_node_value = Read_XML_recurs.GetElementsByTagName("object");..but I have no idea how to read from xdocument..

Comment: @Reshma I have expanded the answer to include a sample loop.